# How to change Button text color in highlighted state for iOS in NativeScript?

Tags: css, ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to change `Button` text color in a highlighted state on iOS using css.

Even though I can change the text color, it seems like some sort of opacity or other styling is also being applied and I can't figure out what it is or how to override it.

This is how the `Button` looks in a default state:
[image]

And this is how it looks in the highlighted state:
[image]

My code:

```
.facebookBtn {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  color: #fff;
  &:highlighted {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: darken(#3b5998, 5%);
  }
}
```

I can tell that the color parameter is working because if I change it to `#000` it works (ofc it is not black either, rather some sort of transparent black).

I've tried applying `opacity: 1;` but it didn't help. It works as it should on Android though.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @heyman I ended up using `MDButton` from https://github.com/nativescript-community/ui-material-components

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution which I've posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new button class that extends `Button` that will not get the default `highlighted`/`tapped` styling in iOS:

```js
import { isIOS, Button } from '@nativescript/core';

export class PlainButton extends Button {
    createNativeView() {
        if (isIOS) {
            return UIButton.buttonWithType(0);
        }
        return super.createNativeView();
    }
}
```

To register this as a global component in nativescript-vue, you can do:

```js
Vue.registerElement("PlainButton", () => PlainButton);
```